# how to make this slider responsive for mobiles

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4, slider, media-queries

i designed this slider and its working good but its not response and i cant use it properly in mobiles, can any one help me just to make it responsive.

fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/iamrahulkumar001/m5yt0pjf/

i have tried using different sliders but none works for me i am using bootstrap 4

https://jsfiddle.net/iamrahulkumar001/m5yt0pjf/ i have the slider working here

```
   <div class="brain_sliders row" style="position: relative;">
 <div id='brain_sliders' class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/super-30-10-07-2019-05-32-06-583.jpg" alt="1 slide"></div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/midori-with-pianist-ieva-jokubaviciute-05-07-2019-12-08-11-888.jpg" alt="2 slide"></div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/bade-miyan-deewane-10-07-2019-03-32-41-494.jpg" alt="3 slide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/mahabharata--the-epic-tale-10-07-2019-11-24-21-041.jpg" alt="4 slide"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/midori-with-pianist-ieva-jokubaviciute-05-07-2019-12-08-11-888.jpg" alt="5 slide"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/bade-miyan-deewane-10-07-2019-03-32-41-494.jpg" alt="6 slide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#brain_sliders" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Geri</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#brain_sliders" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">İleri</span>
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not exactly the right solution, but you can create two sliders. One for resolution less than md (`d-block d-md-none`) and your (`d-none d-md-block`).

I used this solution only once, because I was solving the same problem and needed to solve it quickly.